# Rock Paper Scissors help needed

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Can anyone please help me with this code? Its not working.

```
import Tkinter as t
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random

rockimagepath = "rock.jpg"
paperimagepath = "paper.jpg"
scissorimagepath = "scissor.jpg"


def rockandrock():
    return "The computer also chose rock it's a draw!"

def rockandpaper():
    return "The computer chose paper and it wins. Better luck next time!"

def rockandscissor():
    return "The computer chose scissor and you win!"

def paperandpaper():
    return "The computer also chose paper and it's a draw!"

def paperandscissor():
    return "The computer chose scissor and it wins. Better luck next time!"

def scissorandscissor():
    return "The computer also chose scissor and it's a draw!"

def paperandrock():
    return "The computer chose rock and you win!"

def scissorandrock():
    return "The computer chose rock and it wins. Better luck next time!"

def scissorandpaper():
    return "The computer chose paper and you win!"

def whowon(item1, item2):
    if item1=="rock" and item2=="rock":
        return rockandrock()
    elif item1=="rock" and item2=="paper":
        return rockandpaper()
    elif item1=="rock" and item2=="scissor":
        return rockandscissor()
    elif item1=="paper" and item2=="paper":
        return paperandpaper()
    elif item1=="paper" and item2=="scissor":
        return paperandscissor()
    elif item1=="scissor" and item2=="scissor":
        return scissorandscissor()
    elif item1=="paper" and item2=="rock":
        return paperandrock()
    elif item1=="scissor" and item2=="rock":
        return scissorandrock()
    elif item1=="scissor" and item2=="paper":
        return scissorandpaper()




def rock_click():
    pcrandint = random.randint(1, 3)
    if pcrandint == 1:
        pcoption = "rock"
    elif pcrandint == 2:
        pcoption = "paper"
    elif pcrandint == 3:
        pcoption = "scissor"
    output = whowon(rock, pcoption)
    winna = t.Label(text=output).pack()


def paper_click():
    pcrandint = random.randint(1, 3)
    if pcrandint == 1:
        pcoption = "rock"
    elif pcrandit == 2:
        pcoption = "paper"
    elif pcrandint == 3:
        pcoption = "scissor"
    whowon(paper, pcoption)


def scissor_click():
    pcrandint = random.randint(1, 3)
    if pcrandint == 1:
        pcoption = "rock"
    elif pcrandit == 2:
        pcoption = "paper"
    elif pcrandint == 3:
        pcoption = "scissor"
    whowon(scissor, pcoption)


maingui = t.Tk()

rockphoto = t.PhotoImage(file="rock.gif")
paperphoto = t.PhotoImage(file="paper.gif")
scissorphoto = t.PhotoImage(file="scissor.gif")

rock = t.Button(maingui, image=rockphoto, command=rock_click).pack()
paper = t.Button(maingui, image=paperphoto, command=paper_click).pack()
scissor = t.Button(maingui, image=scissorphoto, command=scissor_click).pack()
```

The problem is that the winner is not being shown. I am just trying to create a tkinter rock paper scissors game in python. I dont know what details to put more. This is just a practice project for impressing some of my friends and family.

Comment: I think you've got enough to get it working now. In the future, it's better to isolate the problem into a small piece of code that doesn't work or doesn't do what you expect. Then explain what you expect to happen vs what actually happens. The program you pasted is quite a lot for people to dig through.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things here.

1. no mainloop. at the end, run `maingui.mainloop()`. I suspect you just forgot to include that.
2. **The main problem is that in your `*_click()` methods, you are passing `rock` as an argument which is actually passing your rock button as an object from the top level context. You need to pass `'rock'`, the string, as the argument.**
3. There are some misspellings - `pcrandit` should be `pcrandint`
4. That's most of it, but you should also add the label at the beginning when you are setting up the images. Then just modify the text when you've decided the winner.

At the end of your code add this:

```
winner = t.Label(maingui)
winner.pack()
```

And then when you want to edit the label, use this:

```
winner['text'] = whowon(...)
```

Should get you what you want. By the way, when you do this:

```
rock = t.Button(maingui, image=rockphoto, command=rock_click).pack()
```

You don't actually get a reference to the button. It does create the button, but rock gets assigned to the return value for `.pack()`

Answer (score 2):

You haven't started the mainloop, So put this at the end:

```
maingui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly reduce the logic of your code like this:

```
def tie(item):
    return "The computer also chose %s it's a draw!" % item

def pc_won(item):
    return "The computer chose %s and it wins. Better luck next time!" % item

def you_won(item):
    return "The computer chose %s and you win!" % item

def who_won(you):
    pc = random.randint(0, 2)
    choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor']
    you = choices.index(you)
    if you == pc:
        return tie(choices[pc])
    flip = you > pc
    if (flip + you - pc) % 2:
        return pc_won(choices[pc])
    else:
        return you_won(choices[pc])

#your code was not consistent for this part        
def rock_click():
    output = who_won('rock')
    winna = t.Label(text=output).pack()

def paper_click():
    who_won('paper')

def scissor_click():
    who_won('scissor')
```